# Undelete own question

Tags: support

I just deleted my own question

[Create Recovery Console disk](https://superuser.com/questions/570500/create-recovery-console-disk)

Can I undelete this? I have been able to undelete answers before. Below an answer is a button for `undelete`. I am looking for a similar button or method for questions.

I was able to get the text back using this type link

https://superuser.com/posts/570500/edit

Comment: FYI When looking for a reference on how it works I found this question, where Sathya explains the details.

Answer (score 1):

I undeleted it for you, but I don't know whether you have the privilege of undeleting questions. I'll have to get back to you on that.